# Need help making many-to-many relationships with CRUD in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I currently have 2 models:
Movie.cs

```
public int MovieId { get; set; }
public Genre Genre { get; set; }
public int GenreId { get; set; }
public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
```

Genre.cs

```
 public int GenreId { get; set; }
 public string GenreName { get; set; }
 public List<Movie> Movies;
```

My Create.cshtml View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GenreId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="GenreId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GenreId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DirectorId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DirectorId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DirectorId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsHot" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsHot)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsNew" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsNew)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieLang" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieLang" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieLang" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieLink" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieLink" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieLink" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MoviePlot" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MoviePlot" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MoviePlot" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieImageFile" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieImageFile" accept="image/*" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieImageFile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieReleaseYear" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieReleaseYear" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieReleaseYear" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CreateDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CreateDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CreateDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieTrailerLink" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieTrailerLink" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieTrailerLink" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

so when I make a View to let Admins create a new Movie it allows them to choose from a dropdown list of Genres.

But now I want a many-to-many relationship which would allow me to add 3,4 Genres into one Movie, how do I make views and models for that?

Comment: This question seems to be too broad. I'd suggest, you focus on one part first, e.g. the model side. Search the internet for "entity framework core many to many" and you'll find good tutorials as a starting point. If you have concrete problems, post them as new question.

Comment: Are you using EntityFrameworkCore as your ORM?

Comment: what is the model type for your view?

Comment: I'm using EntityFrameworkCore, I'm pretty sure I need to make a third model for many-to-many relationship but I can't find an example on the internet that use it. does CRUD still work for many-to-many relationship?

one movie - many genres. one genres - many movies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure I need to make a third model for many-to-many
> relationship but I can't find an example on the internet that use it.

Yes, you need to create a third table to connect the two tables many-to-many relationship, first you need to modify your model, as follows：

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public List<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public List<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
}
 

//Intermediate table
public class MovieGenre
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

You still need to determine the *relationship* between these three tables in **OnModelCreating in the dbcontext file**:

```
 public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genre { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieGenre> MovieGenre { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MovieGenre>()
         .HasKey(bc => new { bc.MovieId, bc.GenreId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<MovieGenre>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Movie)
                .WithMany(b => b.MovieGenres)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.MovieId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MovieGenre>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Genre)
                .WithMany(c => c.MovieGenres)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.GenreId); 
        }
    }
```

Next, you can `pass Movie object and select the list of GenreId` to the controller:

View:

```
@model WebApplication_core_mvc.Models.Movie
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GenreId" name="GenreIdList"  multiple></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
          

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class MMTestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;
        public MMTestController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = _context.Genre.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = a.GenreName,
                Value = a.GenreId.ToString()
            }).ToList();
            ViewBag.GenreId = selectListItems;
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Create(Movie movie, List<int> GenreIdList)
        {
            _context.Movie.Add(movie);

            _context.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var item in GenreIdList)
            {
                MovieGenre movieGenre = new MovieGenre()
                {
                    GenreId = item,
                    MovieId = movie.MovieId,
                    Genre = _context.Genre.Where(x => x.GenreId == item).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Movie = movie
                };
                _context.MovieGenre.Add(movieGenre);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]